# Odd "peers" field from torrent announce

Tags: go, bittorrent

As a fun side-project, I'm trying to write a Bittorrent client in Golang. My test tracker right now is the Ubuntu 20.04.5 iso file found [here](https://ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads). I'm able to get to the point where I'm making a request to the tracker that seems to be registered correctly, but I'm getting the following bencoded string returned to me:

`d8:completei193e10:incompletei4e8:intervali1800e5:peers6:};e`

My big problem is that I can't figure out how to interpret the `peers` field returned here in order to begin making requests to peers. Is there something I'm missing? Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a compact peers list ([BEP 23](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0023.html), and [BEP 07](http://bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0007.html#announce-response) for IPv6). That *should* be an opt-in extension signalled through an additional request parameter, but some trackers send that response type unconditionally.

Comment: Huh okay. I've seen some info about the compact format. So interpreting `:};` in UTF-8, it looks like `[00,3A,00,7D,00,3B]`. This seems to translate to `00.58.00.125:59`. Would this have be reversed to `125.0.58.0` in order to be a valid IP? (I assume this has something to do with endianness...)

Comment: it shouldn't be processed as utf8 but as bytes